# How to set rows values in to one field based on ID in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table called "PERSON"

```
GROUP_ID  PERSON_NAME
1001       ALEX
1002       MATHEW
1001       GEORGE
1002       THOMAS
1001       JAMES
```

I need output like below saperated with `"|"`

```
GROUP_ID   PERSON_NAME
1001       ALEX|GEORGE|JAMES
1002       THOMAS|MATHEW
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a.[GROUP_ID], 
        SUBSTRING(d.Names,1, LEN(d.Names) - 1) NamesList
FROM
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT [GROUP_ID]
            FROM Table1
        ) a
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT [PERSON_NAME] + '|' 
            FROM table1 AS B 
            WHERE A.[GROUP_ID] = B.[GROUP_ID] 
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ) D (Names)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c3e7a/2)

OR

```
SELECT [GROUP_ID],
       STUFF(
           (SELECT '|' + [PERSON_NAME]
            FROM Table1
            WHERE [GROUP_ID] = a.[GROUP_ID]
            FOR XML PATH (''))
            , 1, 1, '')  AS NamesList
FROM Table1 AS a
GROUP BY [GROUP_ID]
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c3e7a/5)